# Building NanoBSD inside a jail

Tags: freebsd, jail

I'm trying to setup a jail to enable building a NanoBSD image. It's actually a jail on top of a NanoBSD install.

The problem I have is that I'm unable to mount the `md` device in order to do the 'build image' part. Is it simply not possible to mount an `md` device inside a jail, or is there some *other* knob I need to twiddle?

On the host

`/etc/rc.conf.local`

```
jail_enable="YES"
jail_mount_enable="YES"
jail_list="build"
jail_set_hostname_allow="NO"
jail_build_hostname="build.vm"
jail_build_ip="192.168.0.100"
jail_build_rootdir="/mnt/zpool0/jails/build/home"
jail_build_devfs_enable="YES"
jail_build_devfs_ruleset="devfsrules_jail_build"
```

`/etc/devfs.rules`

```
[devfsrules_jail_build=5]
# nothing
```

Inside the jail

```
[root@build /usr/obj/nanobsd.PROLIANT_MICROSERVER]# sysctl security.jail
security.jail.param.cpuset.id: 0
security.jail.param.host.hostid: 0
security.jail.param.host.hostuuid: 64
security.jail.param.host.domainname: 256
security.jail.param.host.hostname: 256
security.jail.param.children.max: 0
security.jail.param.children.cur: 0
security.jail.param.enforce_statfs: 0
security.jail.param.securelevel: 0
security.jail.param.path: 1024
security.jail.param.name: 256
security.jail.param.parent: 0
security.jail.param.jid: 0
security.jail.enforce_statfs: 1
security.jail.mount_allowed: 1
security.jail.chflags_allowed: 1
security.jail.allow_raw_sockets: 0
security.jail.sysvipc_allowed: 0
security.jail.socket_unixiproute_only: 1
security.jail.set_hostname_allowed: 0
security.jail.jail_max_af_ips: 255
security.jail.jailed: 1

[root@build /usr/obj/nanobsd.PROLIANT_MICROSERVER]# mdconfig -l
md2 md0 md1
```

`md0` and `md1` are the ramdisks of the host.

`bsdlabel` looks sensible

```
[root@build /usr/obj/nanobsd.PROLIANT_MICROSERVER]# bsdlabel /dev/md2s1
# /dev/md2s1:
8 partitions:
#        size   offset    fstype   [fsize bsize bps/cpg]
  a:  1012016       16    4.2BSD        0     0     0 
  c:  1012032        0    unused        0     0         # "raw" part, don't edit
```

`newfs` runs ok

```
[root@build /usr/obj/nanobsd.PROLIANT_MICROSERVER]# newfs -U /dev/md2s1a
/dev/md2s1a: 494.1MB (1012016 sectors) block size 16384, fragment size 2048
    using 4 cylinder groups of 123.55MB, 7907 blks, 15872 inodes.
    with soft updates
super-block backups (for fsck -b #) at:
 160, 253184, 506208, 759232
```

`mount` fails

```
[root@build /usr/obj/nanobsd.PROLIANT_MICROSERVER]# mount /dev/md2s1a _.mnt/
mount: /dev/md2s1a : Operation not permitted
```

UPDATE:

One of my colleagues pointed out

> There are some file systems types that can't be securely mounted within
>   a jail no matter what, like UFS, MSDOFS, EXTFS, XFS, REISERFS, NTFS,
>   etc.  because the user mounting it has access to raw storage and can
>   corrupt it in a way that it will panic entire system.

From http://www.mail-archive.com/freebsd-hackers@freebsd.org/msg160389.html

So it seems that the standard nanobsd.sh won't run inside a jail while it uses the `md` device to build the image. One potential solution I'll try is to `chroot` from the host into the build jail, rather than `jexec` a shell.

Comment: What about running `mount` with `ktrace`?

Comment: @SaveTheRbtz ah, good idea. I'll try that tonight. `ktrace mount /dev/md2s1a _.mnt/` I'm guessing

Comment: @ptomil, did you have any luck?  I'm interested in tackling something similar, and hoping to learn from your scars.

Comment: @RoyceWilliams I was somewhat successful, in that it's possible to do the build in a chroot environment. It's not possible to do it inside a jail.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, chroot is the way to go.

You don't want to achieve security, just build and change the root so that your installation scripts behave correctly. That's what chroot is for.

On some systems there isn't a chroot binary, but it's kind of easy to code a simple script that will achieve what everything you want (and hey, you can reuse it later!).